# Qual a importância do uso de interfaces em java ou c#?

Tags: java, c#, orientação-a-objetos

Sei como implementar e usar as interfaces, mas não consigo compreender qual o real motivo delas existirem no c# ou java, já que uma vez que você estende sua classe a uma interface é preciso implementar todos os métodos da interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O conceito de desenvolver o código voltado para interfaces vem da necessidade organizar as classes de forma mais coesa, com baixo acoplamento e funcionalidades bem encapsuladas (fundamentos da Orientação a Objeto).

Programar voltado a interface exige abstrair a ideia da implementação. Vou tentar resumir de uma forma bem simplista:

```
public class Empresa {

    public void efetuaPagamento(CNPJ cnpj, double valor){
        String cnpj = cnpj.getNumero();
        ...
    }

    public void efetuaPagamento(CPF cpf, double valor){
        String cnpj = cpf.getNumero();
        ...
    }

}
```

A classe Empresa está acoplada as CPNJ e CPF. Para cada novo tipo de documento  será necessário copiar o método. Para evitar isso, podemos criar uma interface.

```
public interface Documento {

    public String getNumero();
}
```

E então as classes podem implementa-las.

```
public class CNPJ implements Documento {

    public String getNumero(){
        //implementação
    }

    public void validaCNPJ(String cnpj){
        //implementação 
    }
}

public class CPF implements Documento {

    public String getNumero(){
        //implementação
    }

    public void validaCPF(String cpf){
        //implementação 
    }
}
```

Simplificando assim a classe Empresa

```
public class Empresa {

    public void efetuaPagamento(Documento documento, double valor){
        String documento = documento.getNumero();
        ...
        }
}
```

Não se apegue muito no conteúdo dos exemplos, o ponto é entender que qualquer mudança na **implementação** será feita em um único ponto (Classes CNPJ ou CPF). A classe Empresa está **desacoplada**, para ela só interessa receber o número do documento, não importando o tipo do documento. Além de que qualquer novo documento, bastará criar uma classe e implementar o Documento, que não afetará em nada a classe Empresa.

Comment: Eu não sabia que uma interface poderia receber uma classe que implementa a mesma, agora vou poder programar de forma mais otimizada, obrigado.

Comment: @Fells, dessa forma o código fica mais limpo e organizado. Sempre tive a dúvida de como utilizar interfaces. Vou me aprofundar mais nesse assunto porque quero passar a utilizar interfaces nos próximos projetos que desenvolver.

Comment: @DiegoFarias Na minha opinião, a curva de aprendizado da Orientação a Objetos é um pouco longa. Eu mesmo demorei bastante para entender o conceito na prática. Você até compreende quando lê algum artigo ou vê exemplos mas a absorção mesmo só vem depois que você começa a perceber a necessidade de melhorar a qualidade do código no dia a dia. 

Essa apostila da Caelum exemplifica de uma forma bem didática - https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/heranca-reescrita-e-polimorfismo/

Answer (score 5):

Basicamente, uma interface é um contrato, estabelecido normalmente para uso entre dois componentes distintos, como um sistema e uma biblioteca, por exemplo, ou ainda para diminuir restrições no uso de objetos.

Há vários usos. Um dos mais interessantes é o de `IEnumerable<T>` no C#. A implementação de uma enumeração pode não ser um objeto, mas uma função geradora. Vários objetos implementam `IEnumerable<T>`, como `List<T>`, `arrays`, `Collection<T>`, `Queue<T>`, `Stack<T>` e qualquer função cujo retorno seja baseado em `yield return`, que acumula vários retornos de objetos que resultam em uma enumeração pelo método chamador. Este é um caso de redução de restrição: quando declaro:

```
IEnumerable<Objeto> lista;
```

Posso atribuir a ele quaisquer um dos objetos já citados:

```
lista = new List<Objeto>();
lista = new Collection<Objeto>();
lista = new Queue<Objeto>();
lista = new Stack<Objeto>();
lista = new Objeto[10];
lista = MinhaFuncaoComYieldReturn();

public static IEnumerable<Objeto> MinhaFuncaoComYieldReturn()
{
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        yield return new Objeto();
}
```

Além disso, Java e C# são duas linguagens que não suportam herança múltipla. Interfaces são uma boa maneira de garantir que uma classe seja uma composição de várias implementações diferentes.

Um caso emblemático disso é [a classe `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, também do C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, 
IEnumerable, IDictionary, ICollection, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

Ela precisa ser um dicionário, uma enumeração, uma coleção, ter suporte a ordenação e ainda ter métodos em modo somente leitura. Isto garante uma grande quantidade de usos da mesma estrutura de dados.

O Java funciona da mesma forma.

Por último, vale ainda a pena falar de troca de componentes. Suponha por exemplo que temos uma classe implementada em uma biblioteca que por algum motivo não queremos mais usá-la:

```
public class ClasseDaBibliotecaASerRetirada 
{
    public void Metodo1(int i, int j) { ... };
    public int Metodo2() { ... };
    public int[] Metodo3(params int[] parametros) { ... };
}
```

Podemos extrair a interface dela:

```
public interface IClasseDaBibliotecaASerRetirada 
{
    void Metodo1(int i, int j) { ... };
    int Metodo2() { ... };
    int[] Metodo3(params int[] parametros) { ... };
}
```

E implementar outra classe, sem modificar muito do código dependente dessa classe:

```
public class MinhaNovaClasse : IClasseDaBibliotecaASerRetirada 
{
    public void Metodo1(int i, int j) { ... };
    public int Metodo2() { ... };
    public int[] Metodo3(params int[] parametros) { ... };
}
```